# What's the Cypher script to delete a node by ID?

Tags: neo4j, nosql, cypher, graph-databases

In SQL:

`Delete From Person Where ID = 1;`

In Cypher, what's the script to delete a node by ID?

(Edited: ID = Neo4j's internal Node ID)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

(Answer updated for 2024!)

Assuming you're referring to Neo4j's internal element id:

```
MATCH (p:Person) where elementId(p)=1
DETACH DELETE p
```

Assuming you're referring to Neo4j's (legacy) internal id:

```
MATCH (p:Person) where ID(p)=1
DETACH DELETE p
```

If you're referring to your own property 'id' on the node:

```
 MATCH (p:Person {id:1})
 DETACH DELETE p
```

Comment: You could use DETACH DELETE instead of the optional match

Comment: What is 'Person' in this case? is it the 'name" property?

Comment: This works only if you don't want to delete the content in ().

Answer (score 38):

The cleanest sweep for a node with id "x" is

MATCH (n) where id(n) = x
DETACH DELETE n

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/delete/#delete-delete-a-node-with-all-its-relationships

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id

Answer (score 5):

Old question and answered, but to delete node when it has relationships, use `DETACH`

```
MATCH (n) where ID(n)=<your_id> 
DETACH DELETE n
```

or otherwise you get this:

```
Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintValidationFailed: Cannot delete node<21>, because it still has relationships. To delete this node, you must first delete its relationships.
```

It's like SQL's `CASCADE`

Answer (score 2):

When the node is a orphan.

```
Start n=node(1)
Delete n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the link provided by @saad-khan, here's an example for getting the nodes and relationships ids.
The code below shows the ids, so you can make sure that you're deleting everything related to the given ID.

`MATCH (node)-[relation:HAS]->(value)
where ID(node)=1234
RETURN ID(instance), ID(value), ID(r)`

Ps.: ":HAS" is an example of an relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023: the function `id` is [now deprecated](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id), it is advised to use the function `elementId` instead.

It should be noted that the id returned by elementId looks like this:
`4:360c4f42-4aba-47aa-8d1c-dc543cb0cfba:179`

To delete the node:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE elementId(n) = "4:360c4f42-4aba-47aa-8d1c-dc543cb0cfba:179"
DETACH DELETE n;
```